# jQuery slide down one , slide up all?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this script:

```
 <script>
   function toggle(n) {
    $("#panel"+n).slideToggle("slow");
   }
</script>
```

And this HTML file:

```
<div  id="fun1" onClick="toggle(1);">1</div>
<div  id="panel1">
1
</div>
<div id="fun2" onClick="toggle(2);">2</div>
<div  id="panel2">
2
</div>
<div  id="fun3" onClick="toggle(3);">3</div>
<div  id="panel3">
3
</div>
```

When I click one on of them it slide down, but others don't slide up if they already down? How can I let others slide up?

Note: we might have n panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 function toggle(n) {
   $("[id*=panel]").not("#panel"+n).slideUp();
   $("#panel"+n).slideToggle("slow");
 }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwc38x5j/)**

Comment: thanks worked like charm, I will mark it as answered as soon as I can